# Dropping categorical variables with a large number of factors

Tags: r, machine-learning, categorical-data

I have a dataset `data` with 66 variables and around 200,000 observations. A snapshot of the data structure appears below:

```
$ f37: Factor w/ 10 levels "","1","10","2",..: 2 4 4 2 4 2 4 2 2 4 ...  
$ f38: Factor w/ 3509 levels "","100","1000",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...  
$ f39: Factor w/ 15 levels "","1","11","14",..: 7 4 2 4 7 8 15 7 4 4 ...  
$ f40: Factor w/ 15097 levels "","0","1","100",..: 11150 1 5539 1 6710 1650 14680 9235 1 1 ...  
$ f41: num  2156 2156 2156 2156 2156 ...  
$ f42: Factor w/ 14583 levels "","'0503624",..: 11573 1 13170 1 9243 8310 607 1979 1 1 ...  
$ f43: Factor w/ 133655 levels ""," ","(BLANK)",..: 92730 1 2046 1 26944 65286 198 42956 1 1 ...  
$ f44: Factor w/ 145029 levels "","-"," "," 1A8GHB1R76Y123913",..: 49912 1 14207 1 9798 121241 31872 88345 1 1 ...  
$ f45: Factor w/ 124642 levels "","'11291331764964",..: 118266 1 108600 1 14814 3176 46466 99158 1 1 ...  
$ f46: Factor w/ 6524 levels ""," "," HOL 232",..: 85 1 1 1 207 1 1 1  `
```

There are a large number of categorical variables in the data. I would like to exclude categorical variables that have levels larger than a number, *n*, say. This is not only to reduce computation time, but also to ensure that certain machine learning algorithms, such as Random Forests, work.

I have tried the following code:

```
drop_factors <- function(x){
for (j in 1:length(x[1,])) {

        if (is.factor(x[,j])) {
                if(nlevels(x[,j])>32){
                    x[,j]<-NULL
            }
        }

    }
}
```

However, when I try:

```
dropfactors(data)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, , j) : undefined columns selected
```

I would really appreciate any help?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for loop:

```
data[sapply(data, nlevels) <= 32]
```

You receive the error because you change the number of columns of the data frame during the for loop. Hence, `j` might take values larger than the remaining number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this for identify the factor with more than 32 levels :

```
factor32 <- sapply(data, function(x) class(x) == "factor" & nlevels(x) > 32)
data <- data[, !factor32]
```

V